# do while statement in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char a;
    int b,c,d,e;
    int i =0;

    do {
        printf("Enter pet size (s/m/l): ");
        scanf("%s", a);

        printf("Enter number of days: ");
        scanf("%d", b);
        c = b * 8;
        d = b * 11;
        e = b * 14;

        if ( a = 's') 
        {
            printf("Kennelling cost: %d\n", c);
        }
        else if ( a = 'm')
        {
            printf("Kennelling cost: %d\n", d);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Kenneling cost: %d\n", e);
        }
    } while (i =0);

    return 0;
}
```

When trying to enter number of days it completely skips the statement and automatically multiplies with random number. i cant see to know what the problem is the syntax seems to be right as far as i know .

Comment: comparison use `==`. Did You open any C book?

Comment: None of your `scanf` calls is correct. (Also, don't use `scanf` for user input.)

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: gcc gives 6 warnings. You need to fix all compiler warnings, or if you didn't get any, get a better compiler.

Comment: (And I'll club the first person who recommends to use "Yoda conditions" in the head with a blunt Star Wars figure)

Answer (score 2):

'=' is completely different from '=='. by doing `a='s'` or `i=0` you are assigning the value to the variable.

Please use '==' for condition validation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator `=`  in your boolean expressions instead of `==` to make a comparison, which is grammatically valid, but most likely not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected version

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

char a;
int b,c,d,e;
int i =0;

do {
printf("Enter pet size (s/m/l): ");
scanf("%s", &a);

printf("Enter number of days: ");
scanf("%d", &b);
c = b * 8;
d = b * 11;
e = b * 14;

if ( a == 's')
{
  printf("Kennelling cost: %d\n", c);
}
else if ( a == 'm'){
printf("Kennelling cost: %d\n", d);
}
else 
{
printf("Kenneling cost: %d\n", e);
}
} while (i ==0);

}
```

***scanf*** statements not having ***addressof(&)*** operator
***comparison(==)*** operators needed to be used in ***if statements*** instead of ***assignment(=)*** operators.

Comment: None of your `scanf` calls is correct. (Also, don't use `scanf` for user input.)

Comment: None of your scanf calls is correct in the sense? Explain pls. I would like to know my error. @melpomene

Comment: Well, in the first one you're trying to store a string in a single `char`. That's a guaranteed buffer overflow. The more general problem is that you're not checking the return value from `scanf`, so you don't know whether it succeeded (i.e. whether the variable was set at all).

Comment: yeah! I understand my issue now. Can u refer any study source for having a much more cleared understanding about this. Like, how to handle buffer overflow and return values from scanf things and all.

Comment: Any good C book should teach you how function return values work, or how to avoid buffer overflows (i.e. don't store more in an array than what it can hold). That's pretty basic stuff.